# How to store data in backend in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have applied a contact form 7 in a page and want to store the values in backend also. Right now values are going to email id. Please help me. Thank you

Comment: are you using a plugin for the contact form?

Comment: Yes i am using contact form 7

Comment: Looking on the home page it seems you can install flamingo plugin to do exactly that http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/ link to flamingo http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/flamingo/

Comment: I will also put it as an answer so others with same problem can find it

Comment: Sorry to jump into a different scope but I would like to point out that Contact Form 7 is prone to mail bots. I remove mine yesterday as I was getting loads of spam.

Comment: Oliver, did you try the captcha and Akismet Integration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking on the home page it seems you can install flamingo plugin to do exactly that wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7. Link to flamingo [wordpress.org/extend/plugins/flamingo](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/flamingo)

Answer (score 0):

Hook the plugin before the mail is sent.

```
function save_email (&$WPCF7_ContactForm) {

  # write the code to get the email address
  # and save it to your database
  # you might want to use print_r($WPCF7_ContactForm)
  # to get the values used by the form
}
add_action("wpcf7_before_send_mail", "save_email");
```

This [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7-to-database-extension/) might help you if you are not into coding your own stuff.